# Eclipse RCP: How to programmatically get Problems View records

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

On Eclipse Luna, I need to programmatically build java projects and then retrieve the Problems View's records. I use the following code

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
IResource resource = workspace.getRoot();
IMarker[] markers = resource.findMarkers(IMarker.MARKER, true, IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE);
for (IMarker m : markers) {
    System.out.println("Id: " + m.getId());
    System.out.println("Message: " + m.getAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE));
    System.out.println("Source ID: " + m.getAttribute(IMarker.SOURCE_ID));
    System.out.println("Location: " + m.getAttribute(IMarker.LOCATION));
    System.out.println("Line Number: " + m.getAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER));
    System.out.println("Marker: " + m.getAttribute(IMarker.MARKER));
}
```

The message and line number are printed correctly. But IMarker.SOURCE_ID returns "JDT" and IMarker.LOCATION is always null.

Anybody knows how can I get the data shown as "Resource" and "Path" on the Problems View? I cannot create any custom Marker view using MarkerSupportView. I need to access the existing Problems View in a programmatic way. Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Use getResource() instead of getAttribute().

Answer (score 0):

The markers API is pretty flexible, you should read the [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIMarker.html).

Long story short, there will be other attributes that you're not looking at. Try calling getAttributes and dumping them out.